# I am getting a COM error and i need any direction to solve this

Tags: c#, winforms

i got this error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
CLSID `{CCB90152-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719}`

failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Does anyone know what the issue is ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error code 80040154. Class not registered.

This means that one of the classes you are trying to create either directly or indirectly has not been registered with the system.

Make sure you have installed correctly and that all COM entries are present in the registry.

Answer (score 6):

80040154 means that you have tried to instantiate a COM class and that the corresponding COM server (usually a DLL or EXE) has not been registered.

There are two common causes for unregistered COM servers:

- The COM server is not installed on the computer or you have forgotten to register the COM server (e.g. register a COM DLL using regsvr32).
- You are working on a 64-bit operating system and you have registered the COM server for 64-bit but the calling application is 32-bit (or vice versa).

Comment: The 32 bit / 64 bit issue is what it was for me. Thanks!

Comment: I began getting this error when I switched platform target from x86 to Any CPU.